# Ng-class with 2 conditions

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a ng-class:"". And i need to put two conditions in this ng-class. The 2 conditions are, if score is 0 display 0.png picture, if score is 100 display Picture 100.png.

Thanks

Comment: what have you attempted? I mean, this would be just following the normal usage of angular expressions

Comment: Yes im rly new in angular. This one was Easy but ive troubble doing this.  if ive 2 conditions ons is score > 0 && score < 30 and The other is score > 50 && score <= 100 ?. How do i tell which picture to display? If one is named 0 and the other one 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d7jLcgtg/)

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div custom ng-class = "{{(score === 0) ? '1' : ((score === 100) ? '2' : '3')}}"> 
    qwrwqeqwewqe
    </div>
</div>

var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.score = 99;
}])
```

Comment: And if ive 2 conditions ons is score > 0 && score < 30 and The other is score > 50 && score <= 100 ?. How do i tell which picture to display? If one is named 0 and the other one 100.

Comment: Hi @user2345898,

then you need to make a custom directive with your logic use your css of whatever in that.
I can help you if you want exactly want you want.

Comment: Like 
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div custom ng-class = "applyClass"> 
    qwrwqeqwewqe
    </div>
</div>

var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive("custom",function(){
 return {
     restrict:"A",
        link:function(scope,element,attrs){
         if(scope.score > 0 && scope.score < 30 ){
             scope.applyClass = "0";
            }
            else if(scope.score > 50 && scope.score <= 100){
             scope.applyClass = "100";
            }
        }
    }
})

app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
 $scope.score = 99;
}])

Comment: If i want to use images instead shall i put them in css file and reference to the class for each statement?

Comment: yes you can use images through css.
or you can make a directive for the svg vector the latest trande in market svg icons for images like stuff.